# Как добавить PHPdoc comment к уже существующий функции в PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, ide

Есть функция, у которой например 7 параметров, каждый из параметров подробно описан в комментариях Phpdoc над функцией в т.ч. вручную (для каждой переменной дописаны типы данных возможные и описание) + общее описание того что делает функция.

При дописывании или правках функции если какой-то параметр меняется, то комментарий самостоятельно не обновляется и не генерируется дополнительная строка с описанием параметра как это делается при первичном создании описания функции (хоткей `/**` над функцией). 
Как сделать чтобы добавлялся/генерился, не потеряв существующего описания?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изменение, не отраженное в phpdoc будет подчеркнуто волнистой линией. Если установить курсор на эту переменную, то в появившейся "лампочке" появится меню "Update PHPDoc Comment". При выборе этого меню комментарий обновится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в комментарии не хватает, например, тега return, то подчеркнут будет весь комментарий. Изменяется комментарий таким же образом, через выпадающее меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно! А хоткеев нет?

Comment: Нет. Там же все индивидуально: добавить теги, или удалить неиспользуемые, обновить целиком и т.д. И обнаруживается в разных местах.

Comment: Вообще-то если курсор стоит на функции или другом месте и нажатие ALT + Enter вызывает персанализированное меню для данного места и часто используемые функции там есть